# Are ApplicationCommands which manipulate the ViewModel at all intended to be used with MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, mvp

The static class `ApplicationCommands` consists of many `RoutedUICommand`s, some of which could be purely view-based commands (undo/redo, cut/copy/paste), but others would ultimately need to be working with the view model. However, when using one of the latter commands, for example `Save`, there is no clean way to propagate the command to the view model:

```
<CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Save" Executed="Save_Executed" />
</CommandBindings>
....
<MenuItem Command="Save" />
```

This will call the `Save_Executed` event handler on the code-behind class, as it would be used in the MVP pattern, but it will not allow me to move the command to the view model in MVVM, except if using this ugly line in the `Save_Executed` event handler:

```
((ViewModel1)this.DataContext).Save();
```

This is also entirely inconsistent with other commands, such as `RelayCommand`s defined directly in the view model. Because of all these inconveniences, I have the impression that ApplicationCommands were designed with only MVP in mind, not MVVM.

Are commands which need to be propagated to the view model at all usable?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, I think you can do what you're asking if you approach it like this.

**Your ViewModel**

```
// Call this from your ctor
 private void InitializeCommandBindings()
    {
        this.CommandBindings = new CommandBindingCollection(new[]
            {                   
        new CommandBinding(
                    ApplicationCommands.Save,
                    new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(YourEventHandler),
                    new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler((sender, e) => e.CanExecute = Your Logic...))
});
}
```

**Your View**

```
<Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Save}"/>
```

Comment: This only works when I use `CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(*View*), binding)` after this declaration. In which case the type of the `View` must be known to the `ViewModel`. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I have this working by initializing a CommandBindingCollection in my view-model, new-up a CommandBinding and handler, and have the view's button command raise the event.  That's it.  The view-model handles the event and has no knowledge of the view and there's no code-behind.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The command will never get executed; the CanExecute doesn't trigger even once. You can't be bothered uploading an example project or?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the bindings to the view

```
this.CommandBindings.AddRange(((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).CommandBindings);
```